# How to get rolling unique count of employees per year based on key fields

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct-values

I have the following table and I wanted to get the running unique count by dept, team, level. But the cumulative unique count will restart per year.

Note: sorry in my main table example, employee numbers may repeat up to four times. There is another column called leave type but wasn't able to illustrate it in the image

[Main table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rWoE.jpg)

Expected output would be something like below.

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6qj9.jpg)

Is this possible? Apologies. Not too advanced when it comes to SQL. Thank you.

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and post a [mre9 and what you tried

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select max(extract(year from date)), date, department, level, team, count(*)
from t
group by date, department, level, team
```